# Enum.ToString() returns a wrong description c#

Tags: c#, enums, edifact

We have a big Enum class for EDI Fields, just to make a short example, the enums are declared like:

```
[Description("Ebene")]
Ebene,

[Description("Zaehlpunktdaten")]
Zaehlpunktdaten,

[Description("Zaehlpunkt")]
Zaehlpunkt,
```

.
.

Well, the enums works fine when you retrieve them by `EDIEnums.Zaehlpunktdaten.ToString()`, but in some other projects, it returns a wrong value.

If I add a new one in the beginning will return exactly the next one, in this example, if I just had added `Ebene` and I want to retrieve `Zaehlpunktdaten`, it will return me `Zaehlpunkt`.

We have tried also with `=0`, `=1`, `=2` etc, and it doesn't work neither. Also with local references.

Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: It sounds like you've changed the enum without rebuilding all the code that depends on it. That's a bad idea.

Comment: I guess you have duplicate values in enum. Post full enum definition.

Comment: Also, don't expect ToString() to return the description attribute's value.

Comment: If the problem appears in some projects but not others it sounds like the projects exhibiting the bad behavior need to have their references checked and rebuilt.

Comment: If your app must rely on Enum.ToString result, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @JonSkee, we rebuild all the time, we have the DLL on a public folder in which we have the references for the rest of the projects, but, could be that the projects does not get the references from there and use a copied one, I will take a look on it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that was my first attempt, and you're right, but now is clean and the error is still there =(

Comment: @qqbenq Of course, we don't want the description, but for a quickly use we use .ToString() to get the name of the field we want, not the description at all.

Comment: If a clean build still shows the problem, you should be able to provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Crono you're right, it's not a good practice, but we have hundred of fields and it's the only way to type it without errors and so one

Comment: @JonSkeet I did one just to verify this and works fine..

Comment: Right, so you need to work out the difference between that and the situation which fails. There's no way we can guess at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say assembly A defines `MyEnum`.
By default, each enum value is implicitly assigned an integer "index", something like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    X = 1,
    Y = 2,
    Z = 3
}
```

If the source code in assembly B makes use of `MyEnum.Y`, that code will be compiled against the value at index 2.

If you now add a new item at the beginning, the indexes will shift:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    New = 1,
    X = 2,
    Y = 3,
    Z = 4
}
```

Assembly B is still refering to the value at index 2, which is now `X` instead of `Y`. This is the error you're seeing.
This is why adding new enum values is considered a breaking change.

If you expected the enumeration to change, you should have numbered the enum values yourself, instead of using implicit numbering, *before* compiling assembly B.

You now have two options:

1. A possible *workaround* is to add the new value at the end of the enumeration, to avoid shifting the indexes.
   But this is a sloppy workaround.
2. Consider numbering the enum values now *and* rebuild any projects depending on that assembly. It might look like a lot of work, depending on how many projects depend on assembly A, but it'll save you and your co-workers from running into this same issue again in the future.

Comment: We tried adding the numbers and rebuilding and still not working, but could be that the references are not updated correctly, I have to take a look on this.

Comment: @TareqB. Did you rebuild the project that defines the `enum` **and** any other project that depends on this?

Comment: Finally I did the sloppy workaround, the numbering didn't work at all, but I let it also. Thanks.